# Как сделать множественный insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Подскажите, как сделать множественный insert?
Есть массив $userArrayIds = ['34','87','76'] массив большой.

Не ужели делать так

```
foreach( $userArrayIds as $uid ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `message` (message,user_id)"."VALUES('Привет' , '$uid' );";
    $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Как то мне кажется что это не верный путь.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-insert-multiple-rows/

Comment: насколько большой? и откуда вообще берется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала надо подготовить массив, в котором будут все нужные для вставки данные. Каждая строка в нем должна представлять массив данных для одной строки в БД.

```
$array = [
    ['Привет', 22],
    ['Привет', 44],
    ['Привет', 55],
];
```

Остальное уже дело весьма несложной техники. Главное не забывать, что любые данные должны попадать в запрос только через **подготовленные выражения**.

Сначала готовим запрос вида `INSERT INTO t (c1,c1,c3) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?)...`, в котором количество блоков `(?,?,?)` соответствует количеству строк в основном массиве, а количество знаков вопроса в одном блоке - количеству вставляемых в каждую строку значений. Это делается несложным кодом с помощью функции `str_repeat()`.

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `message` (message,user_id) VALUES "; 
$chunk = "(?" . str_repeat(",?", count($array[0]) - 1) . ")"; // получаем (?,?)
$sql .= $chunk . str_repeat(",$chunk", count($array) - 1); // получаем (?,?),(?,?)...
```

После этого выполняем запрос, "схлопывая" исходный двумерный массив в одномерный. Выполнение будет зависеть от версии РНР. Начиная с 8.2 оно делается в одну строчку

```
$db->execute_query($sql, array_merge(...$array));
```

Если же версия более старая, то кода будет чуть больше

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$types = str_repeat("s", count($array) * count($array[0]));
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...array_merge(...$array));
$stmt->execute();
```

Да, и важно забыть навсегда про все эти or `die`, `"Ошибка: "` и `mysqli_error` из прошлого века. Оно, во-первых, не нужно, а во-вторых, в современных версиях РНР всё равно не будет работать