# Вставка одним запросом Oracle PHP

Tags: oracle

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильнее реализовать:
Необходимо произвести массовую вставку в таблицЫ, используя подготовленные запросы, данные для bind взять из массива.
Т.е, что то типа:
Insert into table1 (p1, p2) Values(:p1, :p2)
Insert into table2(pp1, pp2) Values (:pp1, :pp2)
И если подготовить запрос в цикле и вставить запись не вызывает сложности, то как это сделать ОДНИМ запросом(как бы построить большой инсерт, но с использованием функции bindParam) не совсем понятно, примерно понимаю, что нужно использовать транзакцию, но пока не совсем понимаю как.

Стек: Zend Фреймворк, БД Оракл, ЯП - PHP

Comment: так одним запросом или использовать транзакцию? Откуда такое требование - "одним запросом"? В одну таблицу можно вставить одним запросом несколько записей, это несложный код для работы со строками. Но почему в две таблицы надо вставлять одним запросом?

Comment: как сделать одним запросом в одну таблицу, я объяснял [совсем недавно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1566000/179379).Только для ПДО выполнение запроса будет другим, `$db->prepare($sql)->execute(array_merge(...$array));`

Comment: @Akina, перестань пожалуйста давать вредные советы в оракловых топиках.  Не имеешь знаний в этой области - ну промолчи пожалуйста.  В оракле есть [multi-table inserts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2121682).

Comment: @ESkri как скажете...

Comment: Поставим теги в соответствии с ответом, чтобы людей зря не путать

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такая возможность в Оракл:

```
INSERT ALL
 INTO table1 (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
 INTO table2 (column3, column4) VALUES (value3, value4)
SELECT 1 FROM dual;
```